# Why is C/C++ main argv declared as "char* argv[]" rather than just "char* argv"?

Tags: c++, c

Why is `argv` declared as "a pointer to pointer to the first index of the array", rather than just being "a pointer to the first index of array" (`char* argv`)?

Why is the notion of "pointer to pointer" required here?

Comment: "a pointer to pointer to the first index of the array" - That's not a correct description of `char* argv[]` or `char**`. That's a pointer to a pointer to a character; specifically the outer pointer points to the first pointer in an array, and the inner pointers point to the first characters of nul-terminated strings. There's no indices involved here.

Comment: How would you get the second argument if it was just char* argv?

Comment: Your life will get easier when you put the space in the right place. `char*  argv[]` puts the space in the wrong place. Say `char  *argv[]`, and now it is clear that this means "the expression `*argv[n]` is a variable of type `char`". Don't get caught up in trying to work out what's a pointer and what's a pointer to a pointer, and so on. The declaration is telling you what *operations* you can perform on this thing.

Comment: It's NOT.  It's declared as "char **argv", not "char *argv".  That is, a pointer to a list of pointers to char., not a simple pointer to a string of char.  Each individual argument coul be in non-contiguous memory locations.

Comment: Mentally compare `char * argv[]` to the similar C++ construct `std::string argv[]`, and it might be easier to parse.  ...Just don't start actually _writing_ it that way!

Comment: note that some windows programs do receive a char* that contains the whole command line as one string

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash Only programs that use `WinMain` instead of `main`.

Comment: `char` is a character, `char*` is a pointer to a character and by the standard this character is treated as a string terminating with NULL i.e. `'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'`. `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a character meaning an array of strings.

Comment: It is several different strings, not just one. You would need to encode ending of string somehow if you only have one pointer. You could do this null terminated for example. But it has some other drawbacks.

Comment: @EricLippert note that the question also includes C++, and there you can have e.g. `char &func(int);` which doesn't make `&func(5)` have type `char`.

Comment: If it were just char* that would be conceptually a single string.  The arguments list that a command line can pass into the main() method is typically a collection of multiple strings, hence the char** (or char* argv[]).  If the argument values were just a single string, you would need to manually parse and tokenize the arguments yourself in code.  The system does this for you, by splitting on spaces, and generating the array of strings for you.  It handles all the heavy lifting, and regex you may need for handling multiple spaces inside double-quotes as well which can be tricky to code.

Comment: @user000001: Comments which express surprise that people don't know a thing are unhelpful on a Q&A site. The basic premise of a Q&A site is that something is unknown by the person asking the question. A great many programmers do not have degrees, and a great many who do did not study C in programming 101; I studied scheme in my first university programming course, for example.

Answer (score 62):

Argv is basically like this:

[image]

On the left is the argument itself--what's actually passed as an argument to main. That contains the address of an array of pointers. Each of those points to some place in memory containing the text of the corresponding argument that was passed on the command line. Then, at the end of that array there's guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Note that the actual storage for the individual arguments are at least potentially allocated separately from each other, so their addresses in memory might be arranged fairly randomly (but depending on how things happen to be written, they could also be in a single contiguous block of memory--you simply don't know and shouldn't care).

Comment: Whatever layout engine drew that diagram for you has a bug in their minimize-crossings algorithm!

Comment: @EricLippert Could be intentional to emphasize that that the pointees might not be contiguous nor in order.

Comment: I would say it's intentional

Comment: It was certainly intentional--and I'd guess Eric probably figured that, but (correctly, IMO) thought the comment was funny anyway.

Comment: as long as you're running ASLR or TempleOS, i guess this'll happen (ASLR intentionally randomize memory layout, and TempleOS doesn't use virtual memory so it'll just put the arguments wherever there's space for it)

Comment: @hanshenrik Why would ASLR influence in what order the arguments are allocated? All the ASLR implementations I know, randomize code and possibly heap and stack locations, but aren't involved where some allocations are made. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @Voo ASLR doesn't influence the order they're allocated, but it influence the position of the allocations in virtual memory,  so that the first argument may be positioned next to the 3rd argument which is positioned next to the eight argument which is positioned next to the 2nd argument and so on, like in the picture~

Comment: @hanshenrik How would that happen? Sure, since the start position of the heap changes the absolute positions will vary, but how the heap memory is used doesn't depend on ASLR but on the heap manager (I could implement malloc/free using an area allocator - how would that work if ASLR started changing virtual addresses itself?)

Comment: @JerryCoffin, one might also point out that even if the actual arguments were contiguous in memory, they can have arbitrary lengths, so one would still need distinct pointers for each of them to be able to access `argv[i]` without scanning through all the previous ones.

Comment: @Voo at least in OpenBSD, the virtual memory location of every malloc() should be randomized, at least if the malloc size is >= pagesize, and with that in mind i wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/c88e28d31d2272dddad28871a0380a32) to try to find instances where the location of the arguments was off, but no luck.. - it all depends on the allocator tho, including if you use a custom allocator

Comment: @hanshenrik Sure the allocator might randomize the allocation location, but that should be independent of ASLR (although the allocator might decide its behavior based on the ASLR switch). Under Linux (or all Unixes) I'd expect argv to be always in order anyhow, since there's no reason for the kernel to not copy the whole thing as a single longer string into the process and then simply point the pointers at the right part of it. Under Windows I'd expect it to be allocated from the heap since the process has to do some computation at startup, so it might be observable there.

Comment: There isn't a null in the argv array is there?  It's just an array, not a string.

Comment: @Jim The last pointer in argv is per specification NULL (not the string but the pointer value)

Comment: @Jim Since when is argv NULL terminated?  I thought that's why we had argc.  I was serious about "since when", because I learned C before it was ANSI ratified.

Comment: @ErikBennett: At least as far as I can see, that final NULL pointer isn't mentioned in K&R 1, but it is required by the 1989 C standard. I believe it was fairly common pre-standard as well, but can't give references to support that.

Comment: @hanshenrik: Even without anything specifically attempting to randomize locations, it's entirely reasonable for the locations to be fairly random. For one obvious example, it's pretty common for a heap manager to segregate allocations by size, so (for example) arguments less than 16 characters might come from one region, 16-32 from another, and so on.

Comment: @ErikBennett Yeah, I learned C from K&R too.  I'm feeling a little old today... :-)

Answer (score 23):

Because that's what the operating system provides  :-)

Your question is a little bit of a chicken/egg inversion issue. The problem is not to choose what you want in C++, the problem is how you say in C++ what the OS is giving you.

Unix passes an array of "strings", each string being a command argument. In C/C++, a string is a "char*", so an array of strings is char* argv[], or char** argv, according to taste.

Comment: No, it's exactly "the problem to choose what you want in C++". Windows, for example, provides the command line as a single string, and yet C/C++ programs still receive their `argv` array — the runtime takes care of tokenizing the command line and building the `argv` array at the startup.

Comment: @Joker_vD I think in a twisted way it *is* about what the OS gives you. Specifically: I guess C++ did it this way because C did it this way, and C did it this way because at the time C and Unix were so inextricably linked and Unix did it this way.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, this is from C's Unix heritage.  On Unix / Linux a minimal `_start` that calls `main` just needs to pass `main` a pointer to the existing `argv` array in memory; it's already in the right format.  The kernel copies it from the argv argument to the [`execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call that was made to start a new executable.  (On Linux, argv[] (the array itself) and argc are on the stack on process entry.  I assume most Unixes are the same, because that's a good place for it.)

Comment: But Joker's point here is that the C / C++ standards leave it up to the implementation where the args come from; they don't have to be straight from the OS.  On an OS that passes a flat string, a *good* C++ implementation should include tokenizing, instead of setting `argc=2` and passing the whole flat string.  (Following the letter of the standard is not sufficient to be *useful*; it intentionally leaves a lot of room for implementation choices.)  Although some Windows programs will want to treat quotes specially, so real implementations do provide a way to get the flat string, too.

Comment: [Basile's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/385830/165079) is pretty much this + @Joker's correction and my comments, with more details.

Answer (score 17):

First, as a parameter declaration, `char **argv` is the same as `char *argv[]`; they both imply a pointer to (an array or set of one or more possible) pointer(s) to strings.

Next, if you only have "pointer to char" — e.g. just `char *` — then in order to access the nth item, you'll have to scan the first n-1 items to find the nth item's start.  (And this would also impose the requirement that each of the strings are stored contiguously.)

With the array of pointers, you can directly index the nth item — so (while not strictly necessary — assuming the strings are contiguous) it is generally much more convenient.

To illustrate:

./program hello world

```
argc = 3
argv[0] --> "./program\0"
argv[1] --> "hello\0"
argv[2] --> "world\0"
```

It is possible that, in an os provided array of characters:

```
            "./program\0hello\0world\0"
argv[0]      ^
argv[1]                 ^
argv[2]                        ^
```

if argv were just a "pointer to char" you might see

```
       "./program\0hello\0world\0"
argv    ^
```

However (though likely by design of the os) there is no real guarantee that the three strings "./program", "hello", and "world" are contiguous.  Further, this kind of "single pointer to multiple contiguous strings" is a more unusual data type construct (for C), especially compared with array of pointers to string.

Comment: what if instead of , `argv --> "hello\0world\0"` you have `argv --> index 0 of the array` (hello), just like a normal array. why isn't this doable? then you keep reading the array `argc` times. then you pass argv itself and not a pointer to argv.

Comment: @auser, that's what argv --> "./program\0hello\0\world\0" is: a pointer to the first char (i.e. the ".")  If you take that pointer past the first \0, then you have a pointer to "hello\0", and after that to "world\0".  After argc times (hitting \0"), you're done.  Sure, it can be made to work, and as I said, an unusual construct.

Comment: You forgot to state that in your example `argv[4]` is `NULL`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, oh, ok!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why _would_ `argv[4]` be NULL? There's no guarantee of that.

Comment: At least on POSIX there is such a guarantee

Comment: There is a guarantee that (at least initially) `argv[argc] == NULL`.  In this case that's `argv[3]`, not `argv[4]`.

Comment: In your first codeblock you said that `argv[0] = "./program"`. Is that a typo? I would expect, and your later code shows, that `argv[0]` is null-terminated. i.e. `argv[0] = "./program\0"`

Comment: @Hill, yes, thank you as I was trying to be explicit about the null character terminators (and missed that one).

Answer (score 13):

> Why C/C++ main argv is declared as “char* argv[]”

A possible answer is because the **C11 standard** [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (in [§5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1)) **and the C++11 standard** [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (in *§3.6.1 main function*) **require that** for hosted environments (but notice that the C standard mentions also [*§5.1.2.1 freestanding environments*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)) See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498253/841108).

The next question is why did the C and C++ standards choose `main` to have such a `int main(int argc, char**argv)` signature? The explanation is largely historical: [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) was invented with [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix), which has a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) which does [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) before doing [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html) (which is a system call to create a process) and [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) (which is the system call to execute a program), and that `execve` transmits an array of string program arguments and is related to the `main` of the executed program. Read more about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) and about [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s.

And C++ tried hard to follow the conventions of C and be compatible with it. It could not define `main` to be incompatible with C traditions.

If you designed an operating system from scratch (still having a command line interface) and a programming language for it from scratch, you'll be free to invent different program starting conventions. And other programming languages (e.g. Common Lisp or Ocaml or Go) have different program starting conventions.

In practice, `main` is invoked by some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) code. Notice that on Windows the globbing may be done by each program in the equivalent of crt0, and some Windows programs can start thru the non-standard [WinMain entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx). On Unix, globbing is done by the shell (and `crt0` is adapting the ABI, and the initial call stack layout that it has specified, to calling conventions of your C implementation).

Answer (score 12):

Rather than thinking of it as "pointer to pointer", it helps to think of it as "array of strings", with `[]` denoting array and `char*` denoting string. When you run a program, you can pass it one or more command-line arguments and these are reflected in the arguments to `main`: `argc` is the count of arguments and `argv` lets you access individual arguments.

Comment: +1 This! In many languages - bash, PHP, C, C++ - argv is an array of strings. Of this you have to think when you see `char **` or `char *[]`, which is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases the answer is "because it's a standard". To quote [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> — If the value of argc is greater than zero, the **array** members argv[0] through
>   argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain **pointers to strings**, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.

Of course, before it has been standardized it was already in use by K&R C in early Unix implementations, with the purpose of storing command-line parameters (something you have to care in Unix shell such as `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` but not in embedded systems). To quote f[irst edition of K&R's "The C Programming Language" (pg. 110)](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n117):

> The first (conventionally called **argc**) is the number of command-line arguments the program was invoked with; the second (**argv**) is a pointer to an array of character strings that contain the arguments, one per string.